# Zariski density

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth proper variety over a number field. For a positive integer $n$, let $X_n$ be a finite subset of closed points on $X$ such that $|X_{n}| \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Moreover, suppose that the subsets $X_n$ are becoming equidistributed on $X(\mathbb{C})$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. In algebro-geometric sense, can we say that $X_n$ is becoming Zariski dense on $X$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$? In other words, is it somehow possible to make sense of being Zariski dense for finite subsets with size tending to infinity?

Comment: You might ask whether the smallest degree of a polynomial vanishing on $X_n$ is also tending to infinity, for example.

Comment: A measure argument gives that the infinite union of these sets is Zariski dense (ignoring disconnected cases, where a codimension one set might be an irreducible component); is this what you are asking?

Comment: Equidistributed on $X(\mathbb{C})$ in what measure? Better to say dense in the strong (Archimedean) topology; this is the case for any measure in the same class as a Lebesgue measure. What you need to know then is that a Zariski-closed set is also closed in the Archimedean topology (that is to say this topology is stronger than Zariski topology). Mumford's Red book may be a good reference for this basic fact (if I recall correctly). Or any text on several complex variables.

Comment: If you're trying to generalize the notion of equidistribution, then perhaps set $\delta_n$ to be the counting measure on $X_n$, normalized to have total mass $1$, and look at where the limit measure $\lim_{n \to \infty}\delta_n$ is supported.

For example, if $\varphi: X \to X$ is a reasonable (which to me means polarized) endomorphism of degree more than $1$, and $X_n = \varphi^{-n}(\alpha)$ for reasonable $\alpha \in X$, then $X_n$ will equidistribute to a measure supported on the Julia set of $\varphi$, which is Zariski-dense in $X$.